# Dynamic PHP content inside ajax success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create dynamic php content on ajax success like the one below. I keep getting parse error. Not able to figure out the issue. **New to PHP n Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "edit_listing.php",
    data: {value:val},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) { 
        txt="<php echo '<div></div>';"+
            "echo '<p></p>'; ?>";
        $("#someid").append(txt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
txt = '<div></div> <p></p>';
$("#someid").append(txt);
```

**Explanation:** You can create html and show it on page by using JS or JQuery only. There is no requirement of PHP in that.

Comment: I want even to use some if conditions n more, this was just an example. I am building something which uses session variables for more dynamic content.

Comment: Return the value of session variable from ajax call and use in JS

Comment: I thinks thats better idea. Have done that before. Just wondering is there a way to use some thing like this code directly in ajax o/p "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['pictures']) && !empty($_SESSION['pictures'])) {
    echo '<div class="w3-content1" style="width:300px;height:250px;position:relative;overflow:hidden">';
    for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['pictures']);$i++){
        $value=$_SESSION['pictures'][$i]['picture_link'];
 if($i==0){
          echo "<img src=$value class='mySlides' alt='Image' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>";
    } }echo '</div>'; }?>

Comment: There's not. Stick to the way you've done it before.

Comment: Thanks you all. If thats best way. I will stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can do it with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-encode.php). For example:

```js
// php code
<?php $txt = "<div>{$somevar}</div><p>{$anothervar}</p>"; ?>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "edit_listing.php",
    data: {value:val},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        // php code 
        txt=<?php echo json_encode($txt); >;
        $("#someid").append(txt);
    }
});
```